# jquery widget include files

Tags: jquery, user-interface, widget

Is it possible to create jquery widget include files that ONLY contain one specific widget?  If I use the custom ui download builder then it insists on including the ui core.  I want to create a load of individual widget files, plus a file just containing the core.  That way, I can easily include the ui core plus each individual widget that I need for the site, and I can see at a glance which ui widgets are being used by a page, rather than having a single jquery-ui-custom.min.js file where it is not obvious which widgets are included within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('head').append('<script src="http://example.com/widget.js"></script>');`

or if you want to be really clever about it check if the file has been included first.

```
if( ! $('head script[src="http://example.com/widget.js"]').length ){

   $('head').append('<script src="http://example.com/widget.js"></script>');
}
```

which checks if the widget has NOT been loaded then add it otherwise it may conflict and give un-expected results :) .

Comment: Thanks.  I think I may not have phrased my question correctly.  The question relates to the 'creation' of the widget.js file in the first place.  How do I create lots of different widget files, each of which does NOT contain a copy of the core jquery ui code? (the download builder forces me to include the core in each download file)

Comment: I dont think you understand how it works. You only need the core once, and they offer the core because on its own the widget wouldnt work. so if you already have a core file loaded, then you do not need the core file loaded again, its just there incase you dont have it at all

Comment: thanks.  I understand that I need the core, and only once.  So how should I organise my widgets so that I can add in only those widgets that I need for a specific page?

Comment: `if(!$('head script[src="url_goes_here"]').length){$('<script/>').attr('src','url_goes_here').appendTo('head');}` what this does it checks for the script tag on head section if its there dont load it again otherwise load it. if you run it multiple times it will just simply skip every other instance. u can put that under a function like `function load_script(url){...} ` so u dnt need to type it so often :)

Comment: btw jquery ui is so light its not worth the hassle lol just include all the widgets in one file, and core on another you should be fine :) besides loading multiple external files is longer than loading one long file :)